# I can't delete file by .net core 3.1 when the file is opened

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to delete a file by .net core but the problem while the user opens the file I can't delete it, even if I tried to delete it manually Windows show me this Message:

> the action can't be completed because the file is open in IIS worker
> process

And here is my code :

```
public async Task deleteFile(long Id)
        {
var UploadedFilesPath = Path.Combine(hosting.WebRootPath, "UploadedFiles");
   
var file = await _repository.GetAsync(Id);

 if (AbpSession.UserId == file.CreatorUserId) {
                try
                {
                    await _repository.DeleteAsync(Id);
                if (File.Exists(file.docUrl))
                {
                        // If file found, delete it   
                        var filePaht = file.docUrl;
                        await Task.Run(() => {
                            File.Delete(filePaht);
                        });

                    }
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
            else
            {
                   
                    throw new UserFriendlyException("Error");
                    
                }
            
        }
```

Comment: You can't delete a file that is in use, which is what the words in the error message tell you. It also tells you that the file is in use in an IIS worker process.

Comment: but how could I delete it even if it is in use?

Comment: Read the very first sentence of my previous comment. **You can't delete a file that is in use.** Doesn't that provide the answer to your comment? **You can't** seem to be pretty clear to me. I'm not sure how else to say it other than **You can not**. It is not possible to delete a file that is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very natural/normal that you can not delete, it is (in use). (Even windows OS work like this)

You can wait until it is closed (able to be deleted) and then you delete.

Inside this block:

```
      if (File.Exists(file.docUrl))
      {
                // If file found, delete it   
                var filePaht = file.docUrl;
                await Task.Run(() => {
                    File.Delete(filePaht);
                });

       }
```

You should check if it is closed, then delete, like this

```
      if (File.Exists(file.docUrl))
        {
                FileInfo ff = new FileInfo(file.docUrl)
                if (!ff.IsFileOpen())
                 {
                     var filePaht = file.docUrl;
                     await Task.Run(() => {
                     File.Delete(filePaht);
                     });
                 }

         }
```

The `IsFileOpen` extension method can be placed in a static class (for example FileHelpers)

```
public static class FileHelpers
{
    public static bool IsFileOpen(this FileInfo f)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = f.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null) stream.Close();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```